# Run incremental crawl using NCrawler

Tags: solr, web-crawler

When we use NCrawler with SOLR, is there any way to run incremental crawling and indexing? I dont want my crawler to fetch the complete data every time it crawls. Is there any way to make the crawl incrtemental ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not anything built into NCrawler for this. You will need to create your own processing to handle this. However, the extensible `IPipelineStep` mechanism will allow you to  create any process around your crawling that you want. For example you could store each visited url in a database with along with a hash of the page content to determine when pages change and only process the changed pages to the index.

Comment: Ya, Thank you @Paige Cook :) You saved my life!! :D

Comment: And is it possible to access password protected data using NCrawler (if we have the credentials)?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You will need to create a class derived from WebDownloaderV2. Here is some sample code showing how to pass authorization cookies... https://gist.github.com/paigecook/5221158